# Force the browser to download an Html Page instead of rendering it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, download

I have a script that pops up a page in a new window, the data are recieved via an AJAX call.

the code is:

```
$scope.downloadExcell = function () {
            $http.post('/Monitor/DownloadExcell', { model: $scope.formModel })
            .success(function (data) {           

                 var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="
                +"'Content-type' content='application/vnd.ms-excel' />"
                +"<meta http-equiv='content-disposition' content='attachment; filename=fegc.xls' />"
                +"<title>_excell</title></head><body>";

                html = html + "<table style='width:100%;' >";

                html = html + "<tr>";
                for (prop in data[0]) {
                    html = html + "<td>" + prop + "</td>";
                }
                html = html + "</tr>";

                for (key in data) {
                    html = html + "<tr>";
                    for (prop in data[key]) {
                        html = html + "<td>" + data[key][prop] + "</td>";
                    }
                    html = html + "</tr>";
                }

                html = html + "</table>" + "</body>" + "</html>";

                var w = window.open();
                $(w.document.body).html(html);

            });
```

Now, I want the browser to download the page as an .xlsx file
when it's loaded instead of rendering it.

is it possible? Can't figure this one out.

I tried with the meta but they just get ignored.

Thank you!

INFO: this is an ASP.NET MVC WEB APPLICATION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following trick. You create a `<a>` tag and you give him a custom object URL as its `href` attribute.

This will cause the `<a>` to force download with the mimetype set.

You can put your HTML in the `content` variable.

```
var name ='excel-file.xlsx';  // The name of the file to be downloaded
var content = 'data';         // The contents of the file
var mimetype = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'; // The mimetype of the file for the browser to handle

// Add the <a> in the end of the body. Hide it so that it won't mess with your design. 
$('body').append('<a class="download-trigger" style="display:none;"></a>');

var a = $('.download-trigger')[0];
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {
    type: mimetype
}));
a.download = name;
a.textContent = 'Download';
a.click();
```

**Note**: You only need to append the `<a>` to the `<body>` only once, not every time you execute this code.

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/5dyunv6w/ (download will start when you open the page)

Comment: so should the download excell button be an <a>? or do I need to add the <a> alement to the body of the html page i am crating via javascript? I didn't understand

Comment: Yes, the download button should be an `<a>`. You can either put it in the HTML directly or add it via JavaScript. But, iIn case you add it with JS, you need to add it only once!

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that on a with a server side language,

```
// PHP
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filtro.xls");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this funtion to download file.

```
function SaveToDisk(fileURL, fileName) {
                //alert("yes i m working");
                // for non-IE
                if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
                    var save = document.createElement('a');
                    save.href = fileURL;
                    save.target = '_blank';
                    save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

                    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
                        'view': window,
                        'bubbles': true,
                        'cancelable': false
                    });
                    save.dispatchEvent(evt);

                    (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
                }

                // for IE < 11
                else if ( !! window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand)     {
                    var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
                    _window.document.close();
                    _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
                    _window.close();
                }
           }
```

Comment: i dont have to save a file, it's the html content of a page

Comment: **I want the browser to download the page as an .xlsx file when it's loaded instead of rendering it.**